# Sending Email from Rows in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a scenario in which, I've already done some work but for my further process I need some help.

I've a ExcelSheet which is imported to the Grid View and suppose there are 10 records in it. Now I've to send an email and email retrieved from the GridView but I want that at first email will send to first 5 records then after taking 5 seconds email resend to the next 5 records.

Following is my email sending code:

```
void Send_Mail()
    {
        try
        {
            string Pass, FromEmailid, HostAdd;
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in DataGridView.Rows)
            {
                HostAdd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"].ToString();
                FromEmailid = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromMail"].ToString();
                Pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"].ToString();

                Label LblName = gr.FindControl("LblName") as Label;
                Label LblMail = gr.FindControl("LblEmail") as Label;

                string Name = LblName.Text;
                string Mail = LblMail.Text;
                string subject = TxtSubject.Text;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();

                NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromEmailid, Pass);

                client.Host = HostAdd;
                client.Port = 25;
                client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                client.Credentials = credentials;
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                MailAddress from = new MailAddress(FromEmailid);
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Subject = subject;
                msg.Body = ReadTemplate(Name);
                msg.To.Add(Mail);
                msg.From = from;
                client.Send(msg);
                LblMessage.Text = "Email Send Successfully";
                LblMessage.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            LblMessage.Text = Ex.Message;
            LblMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/324059/Using-MSMQ-in-mail-relay)

Comment: Sending 10 emails in ASP.NET doesn't sound like a good idea. Instead, a background program should be sending these. Don't tie up your website threads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take count of the iteration (or use `for` instead of `foreach`) and when you reach the fifth iteration put a `Thread.Sleep(5000);`

Something like that:

```
int counter = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow gr in DataGridView.Rows)
{
    if (counter > 0 && counter % 5.0 == 0)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

//More stuff sending mail...
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: My bad! Check the edit. Now is using float results instead of ints, it should work now.

Comment: Are you sure? on the 6th record it should pass the condition. I made a simple application with a for and this condition and enter when the counter reach the value of 5. Are you sure the counter it's being incremented?

Comment: Sir, if i have to select only 100 records from the excel and after exporting it to the gridview the email send to the 100 records and again select further 100 records and do the same, so how it is possible?

Comment: The simple way to do that it's to store the "5.0" in a variable and modify the value of that variable to make pass more records in a row.
`var limit = 5.0;//Or 100 or whatever`
And then use it in the condition `if (counter > 0 && counter % limit == 0)`